# GDB debug linux application using shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I debugged an application using shared library on target linux system. And I came across the following errors:

```
(gdb) set sysroot /mnt/hgfs/sharefolders/mksdboot-tl/filesystem
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
(gdb)
```

Does the shared library have any problem or the GDB debugger is wrongly configured?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is there a dynamic linker (such as ld.so* or ld-linux.so*) in the directory `/mnt/hgfs/sharefolders/mksdboot-tl/filesystem/lib` ?

Comment: Hello Mark,
Thank you very much.There is no dynamic linker in the path.How can I install a dynamic linker?The linux system is Ubuntu 12.04.3-desktop-i386.And the cross compiler is arm-linux-gnueabifh:gcc version 4.7.3 20130226 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.7-2013.03-20130313 - Linaro GCC 2013.03)

Comment: The sysroot path is meant to be the root of a tree that contains all the shared libraries your remote target can use. It can just contain lib and usr/lib directories, filled with shared libraries, or it can contain a copy of the entire remote filesystem. What does your `/mnt/hgfs/sharefolders/mksdboot-tl/filesystem` directory contain? You may just need to copy over the `/lib/ld-linux.so*` files from your target's filesystem to `/mnt/hgfs/sharefolders/mksdboot-tl/filesystem/lib` .